# Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle in APPNAME UITests-Runner.app

Tags: swift, xctestcase

The application is crashing while i tried to instantiate a viewcontroller from storyboard in XCTestCase class.

Comment: Crash Log plz?? Also check you select storyboard file's target to your testcase target

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 
`Bundle.main` while instantiating your bundle
use

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
```